# Atlassian Rest API: App Properties API always returns 404

Tags: jira-rest-api

I started a new project using `atlas-connect`. Got it running with ngrok, page loads fine in jira cloud. I just can't get or save app properties.

**atlassian-connect.json**

```
{

  "key": "my-app",

  "name": "my-app",

  "description": "my-app",

  "baseUrl": "{{localBaseUrl}}",

  "authentication": {

    "type": "jwt"

  },

  "lifecycle": {

    "installed": "/installed"

  },

  "scopes": [

    "READ",

    "WRITE",

    "ADMIN"

  ],

  "apiMigrations":{

    "signed-install": true

  },

  "modules": {

    "jiraProjectPages": [

      {

        "url": "/my-page/${project.id}",

        "iconURL": "/my-icon.svg",

        "weight": 100,

        "name": {

          "value": "My App"

         },

        "key": "my-app-project-page"

      }

    ]

  }

}
```

**my-page.hbs**

```
...
<script>
...
// GET CONFIGURATION

const getConfiguration = async () => {

  return await AP.request({

    url: '/rest/atlassian-connect/1/addons/my-app/properties',

    type: 'GET',

  })

  .then((data) => {

    return JSON.parse(data.body);

  })

  .catch((error) => {

    AP.flag.create({ title: 'Error getting configuration', body: error.message, type: 'error' });

  })

}
...
</script>
...
```

**result from calling `https://<myinstance>.atlassian.net/rest/atlassian-connect/1/addons/my-app/properties` or when trying to use a PUT request to create a new property:**

```
{
  status-code: 404,
  message: "App with key does not exist."
}
```

What gives?